# How to add If-else condition in same index with different documents by "type" (individually added in doc) in elasticsearch query?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using elastic search 1.6 with java.
    Actually, I am new in elastic queries. in the learning phase.
    Trying some advanced conditions.

I created an index "IndexABCD" in which I have two different document & identified by their "type" field.
    Below I sample document present in elastic.

For example -

```
Doc1
{
    "id":"DS-1",
    "type":"DATASOURCE",
    "name":"test1",
    "category":"cat1",
    "subCategory":"subcat1"
}

Doc2
{
    "id":"FL-1",
    "type":"FLOW",
    "name":"test1"
}

Doc3
{
    "id":"DS-2",
    "type":"DATASOURCE",
    "category":"cat1",
    "subCategory":"subcat1",
    "name":"test2"
}

Doc4
{
    "id":"FL-3",
    "type":"FLOW",
    "name":"test3"
}
```

How can I add following if-else condition which gives an expected output?

```
if(type=="Datasource"){
    category = "cat1";
    subCategory = "subCat1";
}

if(type=="DATASOURCE" && type="FLOW"){
    category = "cat1";
    subCategory = "subCat1";
    &
    don't apply category & subcategory on type FLOW 
}
```

Below query used in my cases but I didn't found the perfect solution for my scenario.
    In the query, If I gave DATASOURCE result like - 2 records in which contains category & subcategory. 
    OR which query will be fit in a current query?

```
Current Query:-    
{
  "query":  
 {
  "filtered" : {
    "query" : {
      "bool" : {
        "must" : [  {
          "bool" : {
            "should" : {
              "terms" : {
                "datasource_and_flow.type" : [ "DATASOURCE" ]
              }
            }
          }
        },{
          "query_string" : {
            "query" : "test*",
            "default_field" : "datasource_and_flow.name"
          }
        } ],
        "should": [
           {
          "bool" : {
            "should" : {
              "terms" : {
                "category" : [ "cat1" ]
              }
            }
          }
        }, {
          "bool" : {
            "should" : {
              "terms" : {
                "sub_category" : [ "subcat2" ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ]
      }
    },        
    "filter" : {      
    }
  }
},
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}, "aggs": {
    "datasource_and_flow.type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type"
      }
    }  
    }
}
```

If We add

```
datasource_and_flow.type = [ "DATASOURCE","FLOW"]
```

now we want

```
total records = 2 records + flow by name "test*"
```

but current query give DATASOURCE type only not getting record from FLOW

For your info - index json mapping - [click here for JSON Mapping file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw-zDPd15zTabmpPU0trLXFiTDA)

Comment: Do you use a mapping when creating your index?

Comment: Yes, I created json mapping file. I will add it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below first filters all docs by "test" keyword, then it applies a should clause where it checks for any 1 criteria out of 2 i.e `(DATASOURCE + cat1 + subcat2) OR (FLOW)`

```
GET _search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "test*",
      "default_field": "name"
    },
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "type": "DATASOURCE"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "category": "cat1"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "sub_category": "subcat1"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "type": "FLOW"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this query gives me only FLOW type records even if i remove below term "datasource_and_flow.type": "FLOW" but i want the DATASOURCE type as well.

Comment: what is 'datasource_and_flow' in your case ? is it the index name ?

Comment: There were some type errors between your doc structure and the query you shared earlier. Since I used your query to edit, the same mistakes creeped into my query as well. Request you to try it now

Comment: @Ajinkya I checked the mapping and the query is correct as per the mapping. Did you used the query as is ?? the filter value for subCategory is subCat2 in my ex whereas it is subcat1 in your docs. Updated as per the mapping. Please check now

Comment: Great. Thanks which works. As per my commitment i gave you bounty.